# How to return a List/Dictionary

Tags: python

```
def pluglistafamilia():
    data = connect('GET', '/plugins/families')
    return list((h['id']) for h in data['family'])

def getfamilia():
    data = connect('GET', '/plugins/families')
    return dict((h['count'], h['name'], h['id']) for h in data['family'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    token = login(username, password)
    d = getfamilia()

    print d
```

I'm receiving the following error message when trying to print either a list or dictionary. I know my syntax is probably wrong. I'm still a beginner.

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: What is "connect()" supposed to return, and how is it declared?

Comment: When you use `list[]`, you need to pass an index number in the `[]`, not strings.

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: connect sends http calls to the api im sending querys to. i did not post everything for simplicity.

Comment: /usr/bin/python2.7 /home/user/ness/nessusplugs.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/ness/nessusplugs.py", line 264, in <module>
    d = getfamilia()
  File "/home/user/ness/nessusplugs.py", line 234, in getfamilia
    return dict((h['count'], h['name'], h['id']) for h in data['family'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what API you're using, it's impossible to tell WHICH part you made a mistake in. Sounds like either `data` or `h` are lists in the line:

```
return dict((h['count'], h['name'], h['id']) for h in data['family'])
```

However you're also going to get another issue when you do get that working.

```
In [2]: dict((1,2,3))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-0c2872d03334> in <module>()
----> 1 dict((1,2,3))

TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence
```

I'm not sure what your dictionary is SUPPOSED to look like, but you'd be better suited doing a dict comp.

```
return {h['count']: (h['name'], h['id']) for h in data['family']}
# or something like that...
```

Comment: [
    {
        "count": 11160,
        "name": "AIX Local Security Checks",
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "count": 498,
        "name": "Amazon Linux Local Security Checks",
        "id": 10
    },
    {
        "count": 102,
        "name": "Backdoors",
        "id": 22
    },
    {
        "count": 1872,
        "name": "CentOS Local Security Checks",
        "id": 3
    },
    {
        "count": 3222,
        "name": "CGI abuses",
        "id": 8
    },
   
    }

Comment: above is an example , i could not list the whole example because of size.

Comment: the resource is " family "

Comment: @wwi is that `data['family']`?

Comment: yes family is the resource

Comment: @wwi I'd say that one of the elements that `data['family']` returns is not a dictionary. If that's not the case, then the error isn't caused in the code you posted and it's just being caught there (maybe `data` got renamed??) You can test with `assert all(isinstance(h, dict) for h in data['family'])`

Comment: ill try the dictionary changes  mentioned metnioned above. how would i return a list?

Comment: @wwi I'm not really sure what your list is supposed to have in it, so it's impossible to know. Do you just want `[(11160, 'AIX Local Security Checks', 2), (498, 'Amazon Linux Local Security Checks', 10), (102, 'Backdoors', 22), ...]` (per your data above)

Comment: i would like a list of the 3rd digit which is the id , so in above example its the numbers [2,10,22].

Comment: however a dictionary would also be nice.. based on the same id above..so 2: aix security checks , 11160

Comment: @wwi I'm confused -- isn't that exactly what `pluglistafamilia` does?

Comment: in pluginlistafamilia im trying to return the list  [2,10,22]